# Setting log level for JobRunr

Tags: java, jobrunr

I am using the JobRunr framework, but cannot set the log level, which is "DEBUG" by default.

Did Google research, but to no avail.

This is how I initialize JobRunr:

`JobRunr.configure().useStorageProvider(new InMemoryStorageProvider()).useBackgroundJobServer().initialize();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JobRunr uses the default log level you setup using SLF4J.

If you add a SLF4J implementation (e.g. logback), you can configure everything using logback.xml or via spring boot.